# React double-sided card flip

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

I created a small React app that displays Pokemon cards.  There's a Card component made up of two divs that represent a front and backside for each card using a `card-front` and `card-back` className.  When a card element is clicked, the card flips from `0%, 50% rotateY(180deg) to 100% rotateY(360deg)` using a transform rotate animation, but the image displays at all times.  I'd like for the card to not display the image at the `180deg` rotation, just displaying the card background color, like the backside of a card, then display the new image on the last animation at `360deg`.  The way it works now, the card displays the image, it is clicked and the image changes, the card appears to rotate but the image remains on display.  What can I do to get the sequence to:

1. Click the card then flip from 0 to 180
2. The 180deg flip shows a solid color, no image
3. The 360deg, last animation, shows the new image.

I tried wrapping the `if (card.clicked)…` statement in a setTimeout function and have it run at half the time (0.25s) the full animation takes to run (0.5s). I did that to at least slow down the time the api call would update the image on the card, but it seemed a bit hackish. That also causes some random cards on the page to flip twice.  I'm not exactly sure how to get this all to run in sequence smoothly in React.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Scoreboard } from './Scoreboard';
import { Card } from './Card';

function shuffleArray(array) {
  let newArray = [...array];
  let currentIndex = newArray.length,
    randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle
  while (currentIndex !== 0) {
    // Pick a remaining element
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;

    // And swap it with the current element
    [newArray[currentIndex], newArray[randomIndex]] = [
      newArray[randomIndex],
      newArray[currentIndex],
    ];
  }

  return newArray;
}

function GamePage() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  const [currentScore, setCurrentScore] = useState(0);
  const [highScore, setHighScore] = useState(0);
  const [animationTrigger, setAnimationTrigger] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Call PokeAPI
    fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=12')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const cards = data.results.map((pokemon, index) => ({
          id: index,
          image:
            // Poke API image library
            `https://github.com/sashafirsov/pokeapi-sprites/blob/master/sprites/pokemon/other/dream-world/${
              index + 1
            }.svg?raw=true` || '../images/pokeball.svg',
        }));

        setCards(cards);
      });
  }, []);

  function handleCardClick(id) {
    // Find the card that was clicked
    setAnimationTrigger(count => count + 1);
    const card = cards.find(card => card.id === id);
    const shuffledCards = shuffleArray([...cards]);

    if (card.clicked) {
      // Reset the game if the same card was clicked
      setCards(shuffledCards.map(card => ({ ...card, clicked: false })));
      setCurrentScore(0);
    } else {
      // Update the card to clicked true
      setCards(
        shuffledCards.map(card =>
          card.id === id ? { ...card, clicked: true } : card
        )
      );
      setCurrentScore(currentScore + 1);
      // Update the high score
      if (currentScore + 1 > highScore) {
        setHighScore(currentScore + 1);
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Let&apos;s Play</h1>
      <Scoreboard currentScore={currentScore} highScore={highScore} />
      <div className='game-board'>
        {cards.map(card => (
          <Card
            key={`${card.id}-${animationTrigger}`}
            image={card.image}
            onClick={() => handleCardClick(card.id)}
            className='card-shuffle-animation'
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export { GamePage };


import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
function Card({ image, onClick, className }) {
  return (
    <div className={`card ${className}`} onClick={onClick}>
      <div className='card-inner'>
        <div className='card-front'>
          <img src={image} className='card-img' alt='Pokemon' />
        </div>
        <div className='card-back'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Card.propTypes = {
  image: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  className: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export { Card };


/* Card */
.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--poke-brown);
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.card-img {
  max-width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
}

@keyframes shuffle {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

.card-shuffle-animation {
  animation: shuffle 0.5s ease forwards;
}

.card:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2em var(--light-bg));
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component background is not covering your parent div, I gave `position: absolute` to fix this and another animation to manage visibility of `card-back` as you want to show it just in 180deg

Here is the css

```
.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  background-color: var(--poke-brown);
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.card-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  animation: shuffle 0.5s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes shuffle {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

.card-front,
.card-back {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card-img {
  max-width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  transition: visibility 0.25s ease;
}

.card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-color: black; 
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showBackground 0.5s ease forwards;
}

.card:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2em var(--light-bg));
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes showBackground {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; 
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1; 
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0; 
  }
}

.card-front {
  background-color: var(--poke-brown);
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.card-back {
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

and working prototype for css part (I did not change your react code since it was a css question)
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/affectionate-fog-wk9szz

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I also added a `hideShowImage` animation to your recommendation to hide the img on the card until the animation ends in order to delay, visually, the new fetched image after the flip happens.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/twilight-pond-qwvwzz?file=%2Fsrc%2FCard%2FCard.css%3A68%2C7